# Как заставить постоянно работать участок кода? И как сделать это более правильнее?

Tags: c#, discord, .net-core

Делаю кастомный DiscordRPC в c#, и мне нужно постоянно вызывать `discordRpcClient.Invoke()` для отображения сведений в самом дискорде. While не подойдет.

Comment: `While не подойдет.` - почему? Делаете `Task`, в нем бесконечный цикл, задежку если надо и все, асиннхронно, фоном выполняет нужную вам логику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В C# есть такая штука, как таймеры. Можно указать через какой промежуток времени и что вызывать.
Создаёте нужную вам функцию и настраиваете таймер.
Делается буквально парой строчек
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.9.php